# Конкатенация $sql в функции mysqli_query()

Tags: php

подскажите пожалуйста, почему функция `$mysqli->query()` не выполняется если произвести конкатенацию переменных?

```
$sql = "
        INSERT INTO oc_product
        (product_id, model, sku, upc, ean, jan, isbn, mpn, location, quantity, stock_status_id, image, manufacturer_id, shipping, price, points, tax_class_id, date_available, weight, weight_class_id, length, width, height, length_class_id, subtract, minimum, sort_order, status, viewed, date_added, date_modified, dc_label_one, dc_label_two, dc_shortstory)
        VALUES
        ('{$id}', '{$model}', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1000', '7', '{$image}', '0', '1', '{$price}', '0', '0', '{$date_available}', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '{$date_added}', '{$date_modified}', '', '', '');
    ";
    $sql .= "
        INSERT INTO oc_product_description
        (product_id, language_id, name, description, tag, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keyword)
        VALUES
        ('{$id}', '2', '{$name}', '{$description}', '', '{$name}', '', '');
    ";

$mysqli->query($sql);
```

Сам SQL запрос прекрасно выполняется, в чём проблема?

Comment: ошибки выдает ?

Comment: Потому что не поддерживает. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Akina, оформите ответ, выберу ваш ответ правильным. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

## Правильный ответ:

Никакой конкатенацией заниматься не нужно. Запросы в которых участвуют переменные, должны выполняться с помощью **подготовленных выражений**.
Поэтому запросы выполняются по отдельности.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO oc_product
    (product_id, model, sku, upc, ean, jan, isbn, mpn, location, quantity, stock_status_id, image, manufacturer_id, shipping, price, points, tax_class_id, date_available, weight, weight_class_id, length, width, height, length_class_id, subtract, minimum, sort_order, status, viewed, date_added, date_modified, dc_label_one, dc_label_two, dc_shortstory)
    VALUES
    (?, ?, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1000', '7', ?, '0', '1', ?, '0', '0', ?, '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', ?, ?, '', '', '');
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$id,$model,$image,$price,$date_available,$date_added,$date_modified);
$stmt->execute();
$sql = "INSERT INTO oc_product_description
    (product_id, language_id, name, description, tag, meta_title, meta_description, meta_keyword)
    VALUES
    (?, '2', ?, ?, '', ?, '', '');
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss",$id,$name,$description,$name);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: отдельный вопрос, зачем пихать туда заведомо пустые столбцы и числа в виде срок.